# Mule uses old Joda Time version

Tags: java, maven, mule

Jira ticket: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7707

How do I override the version in my connector? This is what I did in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dynamodb-connector ---
[INFO] org.mule.modules:dynamodb-connector:mule-module:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |           \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-json:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.kitchen-eel:json-schema-validator:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-cxf:jar:3.5.0:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jibx:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.2.4.5:provided
[INFO]    |     \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO]       \- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.9:provided
[INFO]          \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:provided
[INFO]             \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:provided
[INFO]                \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:provided
[INFO]                   \- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
```

I'm not sure why it keeps complaining `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule 3.6 is being released very soon including [MULE-7936](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7936), and therefor an fully tested Mule with an update joda-time. I would recommend to wait for it or to manually backport and keep developing with that version until 3.6 gets released.

Comment: thanks! that's good to know. Do you know why it keeps using the old version though? when my dependency tree says joda-time v2.2 is installed?

Comment: I installed Mule server 3.6.0 M2 EE but it's still using joda-time 1.6

Comment: The issue MULE-7936 was fixed in 3.6.0 RC1, which does not seem to be available for download, but that is a later release than 3.6.0 M2. So I guess we will just have to wait for the final 3.6.0 release.

Comment: Even if your application does include the lastest joda the mule container will still contain the older one. If the container is under your control you could remove that jar otherwise you should use an [exclusion](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule).

Comment: @VíctorRomero I put `loader.override=-joda-time` in `mule-deploy.properties`. It seems to work. Is this the correct way to do it?